# Replacing dishwasher pump motor

Tags: repair, appliances, dishwasher, replacement, seal

I’m trying to replace the dishwasher pump motor on my whirlpool. I wanted to just replace the pump motor as that is the part that has gone bad (water isn’t circulating to the arms). I disassembled everything required to get the entire sump and motor assembly at the bottom of the dishwasher. I cut the clamp on the rubber hose on the old motor and am trying to pull it out from the sump but there’s a seal/gasket that it appears to be stuck on - it won’t come loose when I pull on it. Any ideas? I’d rather not have to pay to buy an entire new assembly since the diverter and drain pump work fine. Any ideas what’s going on and how I can break the seal loose without breaking it and then having to worry about finding a replacement seal? Please see attached photos[image][image]

[image]

Comment: If there is just a sealer, it might just be struck, and needs some elbow grease.  If a glue/adhesive might be impossible.  Would try a mini screwdriver to try to work around the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the new pump came without the top rubber seal, do not damage it, or buy a spare.

Using butter knife you help to separate it doing it without damage.

Pulling and twisting (left/right) will help to loosen it.

The next step would be to pull the assembly down, out of the top rubber seal.

When assembling use just silicon grease, no glue.

**BUT**

judging from the picture you did not get the right part. Compare the bottom part of the two.

Comment: Thank you- I just got it free. I just uploaded a pic of the back of the old motor if that helps. I did notice the new motor looks slightly different but I figured that wasn’t a concern but based on what you said, maybe I should double check. I got it from “appliance parts 365” and I asked them directly what the replacement part was for it. It’s a whirlpool WDTA50SAHZ0 dishwasher and they directed me to: https://www.applianceparts365.com/dishwasher-pump-motor-for-whirlpool-part-w11084656

Comment: @Dave i can't tell if it will fit from one picture, you decide on that.

Comment: @Dave https://youtu.be/j3q_mXyYXSE

Answer (score 2):

Try prying the seal off with a butter knife or small putty knife. There's probably scum that's seeped in between the two surfaces and hardened.